# ValueError: ('Error when checking model input: expected no data, but got:', array)

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to build an inception and resnet model with my own image data. The dataset is 8000 images in total and has 6 labels. Everything goes fine while building the model. But the mentioned error occurs in the `model.fit()`.
I'm really not sure what the problem after spending 14 hours.

I tried the following

1. Changing the image dimension ordering
2. Making changes to keras.json
3. changing the input_tensor shape in the model

Image of the error : [image]

```py
inception_model = InceptionV3(input_tensor = inception_model.input, include_top = True, weights = 'imagenet')
inception_last_layer = inception_model.get_layer('predictions').output
inception_out = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', name='output')(inception_last_layer)
custom_inception = Model(inception_model.input, inception_out)

for layer in custom_inception.layers[:-3]:
        layer.trainable = False

custom_inception.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy', 'mse', 'mae', 'mape'])
train_inception = custom_inception.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=8, epochs=2)
```

EDIT: I'm currently using keras 2.2.0 which I downgraded from latest version after going through some keras issues in github. It did solve some initial hiccups. I'm currently using inception and resnet from their respective python files which I made some changes `include_top=include_top` to 
`require_flatten=include_top` from [this](https://github.com/rcmalli/keras-vggface/issues/14)

EDIT2: Here are the inputs shapes

```
(1690, 220, 220, 1)  is the X_train shape
(1690, 6)  is the y_train 
(423, 220, 220, 1)  is the X_test shape
(423, 6)  is the y_test
```

Comment: Could you provide the result of **X_train.shape**, and **y_train.shape** ?

Comment: Sure I will add a detailed png of shapes in a sec

Comment: You can just copy and paste the result, separated by ```python ```, it would appear cleaner.

Comment: what is the object : **inception_model.input**, is it a tensor ? If you are using [this version fo inception] (https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/inception_v3.py) it looks like your model does not require this argument in the constructor.

Comment: Yes, Its a tensor with shape(None, image_rows, image_cols, channels)

Comment: I'm using (https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/blob/master/inception_v3.py) version of inception with changes made as per (https://github.com/rcmalli/keras-vggface/issues/14)

Comment: I reran the code as per your input and it throws (ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_2 to have shape (299, 299, 3) but got array with shape (220, 220, 1)). So should I reshape my image to (299,299,3)??

Comment: (299, 299, 3) suggest that you would feed 299x299 color images, and you have 200 * 200 black and white images. Now apparently you can use different image sizes but they have to be color images?

Comment: Yes, I get that by why is that a constraint? as keeping 3 channels increases the dimensionality and hence the complexity while colours having literally no impact on classification. Is there a way we can ward off that constraint?

Comment: You can redifine the model with 1 channel, it will be more efficicient and require way less parameters, it looks like the only thing you need to rewrite is the function ```def conv2d_bn```

Comment: So I can change lines 72 to 75 in (https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/blob/master/inception_v3.py) is what you're meaning?

Comment: Yes, but you won't be able to re-use the pre-trained weights as your model won't have the same dimensions anymore.

Comment: Yeah, that's another pain! 
Thanks for helping me till now... I will have to find a workaround for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this problem by the following steps:

```
input_tensor=Input((300,300,3))
```

in place of

```
input_tensor = inception_model.input
```

2. Upgrading tensorflow and keras to 1.13.1 and 2.2.4
3. Defining the model with input shape`(300,300,3)` and stacking my `(300,300,1)` input thrice on channel axis inorder to match `(300,300,3)`